# Correct implementation of PHPass

Tags: php, passwords, phpass

I'm using PHPass to store users passwords in my application because it's more secure than md5 or sha1. I have a question about how I would use a salt with the passwords.

From what I gathered, I use it like this when you insert a user:

```
$pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
$hash = $pwdHasher->HashPassword($input_password);
```

and then when you check the users details on login, you do:

```
$pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
if ($pwdHasher->CheckPassword($input_password, $hash_from_db)) {
    echo 'password correct';
} else {
    echo 'wrong credentials';
}
```

But I see nothing there that uses a salt. From what I've read, my user table should have an extra field for a salt that is used when hashing the password, but the `CheckPassword` method of PHPass doesn't take a salt?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the salt contained in a phpass hash or do you need to salt its input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596348/is-the-salt-contained-in-a-phpass-hash-or-do-you-need-to-salt-its-input)

Comment: I would offcourse tell you to use my library instead. But that would just be wrong. PHPass might create the salt itself, and then store it inside the hash. Just from a quick look at the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phpass adds a salt when it hashes the password so there's no need to add a separate salt and store it in your database.